# How to share Keyboard and Mouse Via Bluetooth? (Like in windows Control)

Tags: usb, bluetooth

*** Edited: (or rather, Added to)

## Once upon a time...)

---

**The Goal**
After pairing A Host Windows machine to a...
1. -Another windows machine
2. -Android machine: Phone/tablet/etc...
I can use my Hosts Keyboard and mouse to control it.
I cannot do this in Ubuntu 
(Better said, I do not know how and cannot find the right keyword to search for in synaptic)
 Any help would be appreciated.

-   -

## Meanwhile 6 years, 3 months later...

I have been looking for a way to emulate a native/standard (USB/PS2) Bluetooth HID Keyboard and mouse via a computer: Be it a linux Desktop/Laptop or Android Linux... Linux.

The end-goal simply is to connect to a bluetooth Keyboard and mouse HID compatible device... from a linux based operating system.

Even if it means...

- learning some obscure software, that i am as yet unaware of.
- connecting using a second Keyboard and mouse
- buying a special USB, PCIe (or even pci) or other extra component.
- buying a certain kind of computer, PDA, Phone, single board, etc...
- or if all else fails buying a special standalone device, which is recognized as a standard bluetooth HID...to achieve this.

Can anyone hint me in a direction?

Comment: Does it have to be via Bluetooth? Have you looked at Synergy? http://synergy-foss.org/

Comment: Synergy works fine for Windows/Linux machines, but not android.

Comment: Apparently there is an Android client: http://sourceforge.net/projects/synergyandroid/

Comment: I understand I could create a work around. But what I want is a native bluetooth stack integration (even if i have to install it manually)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clone this Github repository: https://github.com/kcolford/hidclient

```
git clone https://github.com/kcolford/hidclient
```

Edit the `hidclient.c` and comment out `#include <stropts.h>` (line number 105)

Build it

```
gcc -o hidclient -O2 -lbluetooth -Wall hidclient.c
```

List all input devices:

```
sudo ./hidclient -l
```

The output would look similar to this:

```
[severus@tux hidclient]$ sudo ./hidclient -l
List of available input devices:
num Vendor/Product, Name, -x compatible (x/-)
 0  [0000:0005.0000] 'Lid Switch' (-)
 1  [0000:0001.0000] 'Power Button' (+)
 2  [0000:0001.0000] 'Power Button' (+)
 3  [0001:0001.ab41] 'AT Translated Set 2 keyboard' (+)
 4  [0000:0000.0000] 'HP Wireless hotkeys' (+)
 5  [001f:0001.0100] 'PC Speaker' (-)
 6  [0000:0000.0000] 'HDA Intel PCH Mic' (-)
 7  [0000:0000.0000] 'HDA Intel PCH Headphone' (-)
 8  [0000:0006.0000] 'Video Bus' (+)
 9  [0000:0006.0000] 'Video Bus' (+)
10  [0000:0000.0000] 'HP WMI hotkeys' (+)
11  [0000:0000.0000] 'HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=3' (-)
12  [0000:0000.0000] 'HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=7' (-)
13  [0000:0000.0000] 'HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=8' (-)
14  [0000:0000.0000] 'HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=9' (-)
15  [0000:0000.0000] 'HDA Intel HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm=10' (-)
[severus@tux hidclient]$
```

If you want to expose keyboard (say) bluetooth,

```
sudo ./hidclient -e3 -x
```

`-x` to disable it on host.

Note: If you get error related to SDP server, you might want to enable `compat` to support some of the depreciated functions. For that, refer: https://askubuntu.com/a/814969/497359

Comment: And can I theoretically configure this to launch with a dedicated Keyboard and mouse?

Comment: I believe I just answered my own question upon more patient reading... :) very nice... I had no idea what to search, and you have given me the right direction.

Comment: I just cannot seem to get any of the HIDClient solutions to this problem working. No apparent error messages, and the Ubuntu bluetooth settings manager says it's connected to my phone, but the phone just doesn't respond when I hit keys.