# Unified Remote: Bluetooth: Could not connect to SDP

Tags: networking, bluetooth

I installed Unified Remote today in hope that I can use it with my bluetooth adapter to control my PC using my phone. But as I installed Unified Remote and loaded up the web interface, I got this error:

Bluetooth: Could not connect to SDP

Google has absoluetly nothing helpful about this error so this is one of my only chances here.

some outputs:

```
noneatme@noneatme-desktop:/etc/bluetooth$ sudo sdptool browse local
Failed to connect to SDP server on FF:FF:FF:00:00:00: Connection refused

Ubuntu 16.04

noneatme@noneatme-desktop:/etc/bluetooth$ uname -a
Linux noneatme-desktop 4.4.0-22-generic #40-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 12 22:03:46 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

noneatme@noneatme-desktop:/etc/bluetooth$ /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd -C
D-Bus setup failed: Connection ":1.129" is not allowed to own the service "org.bluez" due to security policies in the configuration file
(it works with sudo)
```

Starting Bluetoothd with --compat argument won't fix the problem.

What can I do?

/edit: I fixed this problem by starting the unified remote server as sudo. Is this really the only option I have?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to run the bluetooth daemon in compatibility mode to provide deprecated command line interfaces. You're running Bluez5 and you need some Bluez4 functions. You can do this by editing this file

`/etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.bluez.service`
and changing this line

`ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd`
to this

`ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd --compat`

and then restarting bluetooth like this

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```

and you'll also have to change permissions on `/var/run/sdp`

```
sudo chmod 777 /var/run/sdp
```

and finally restart unified remote server

Comment: Thank you for your help. Can you also let me know how would you make the permission permanent? At the moment when restarting my pc, the permission is lost. Thanks

Comment: Sorry to bump, I also want to know how to make the permission permanent because I am running into the same issue. The above fix  worked but I want to make it automatic whenever I boot.

Comment: I am on debian and I do not have this file =/

Comment: in 2021 this fix worked briefly then stopped working. Did something change?

Comment: This works but blocks my headset to connect to the same bluetooth. (It connects, but doesn't appear in sound devices.)

Answer (score 7):

Another solution:

Edit /etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.bluez.service:

```
ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd --compat
ExecStartPost=/bin/chmod 777 /var/run/sdp
```

Because permissions of /var/run/sdp seems to reset on every reboot.

Comment: I am on debian and I do not have this file =/

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get it working by creating a new `systemd` service.

1. Create a config file named `/etc/systemd/system/urserver.service` with contents of:

   ```
   [Unit]
   Description=Unified Remote Server
   After=syslog.target network.target

   [Service]
   Environment="HOME=/opt/urserver"
   Type=forking
   PIDFile=/opt/urserver/.urserver/urserver.pid
   ExecStartPre=/bin/chmod 777 /var/run/sdp
   ExecStart=/opt/urserver/urserver-start --no-manager --no-notify
   ExecStop=/opt/urserver/urserver-stop

   RemainAfterExit=no
   Restart=on-failure
   RestartSec=5s

   [Install]
   WantedBy=default.target
   ```
2. Set the permissions on the file:

   ```
   sudo chmod a+x /etc/systemd/system/urserver.service
   ```
3. Reload `systemd` daemon:

   ```
   sudo systemctl daemon-reload
   ```
4. Start the actual service:

   ```
   sudo systemctl start urserver
   ```

You should disable "Automatically start server when OS starts up." from Unified Remote Settings (web interface), because `systemd` will start the service automatically. `systemd` will also restart service if it crashes for some reason.

Edited: Environment and PIDFile, thanks to Niklas

Comment: I'd like to suggest an improvement to the above configuration. `urserver-start` now runs as root and attempts to create the pidfile, .config directory and .remotes directory in the system root. If you set it to run as another user then modifying the permissions on /var/run/sdp fails. What I did was to change the environment for `urserver-start` by adding `Environment="HOME=/opt/urserver"`and changing `PIDFile=/opt/urserver/.urserver/urserver.pid` under `[Service]`. Now it starts without errors and stray or missing directories.

Comment: This answer, together with adding `--compat` for the bluetooth service, should really be the accepted answer since it's a persistent solution across multiple reboots.

Comment: Execute permissions should not be needed on systemd service files, as they are no scripts. Please remove the chmod.

Comment: To enable automatic start on boot `systemctl enable urserver.service` may be run.

Answer (score 0):

I combined the other answers to get this working and make it persist through reboots. Here is a step-by-step guide to get it working:

Uncheck the "Automatically start server when OS starts up." box in the Unified Remote settings GUI.

Stop urserver. You can do this with:

```
    user@machine:~$ sudo killall urserver
```

Next as [Leo Pedraza](https://askubuntu.com/users/584821/leo-pedraza) said edit /etc/systemd/system/dbus-org.bluez.service and change this line

```
    ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd
```

to this

```
    ExecStart=/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd --compat
```

Then do as [Esa Nikulainen](https://askubuntu.com/users/855704/esa-nikulainen) and [Niklas](https://askubuntu.com/users/10609/niklas) suggested and create a new systemd service like so:

Create a config file named /etc/systemd/system/urserver.service with contents of:

```
    [Unit]
    Description=Unified Remote Server
    After=syslog.target network.target

    [Service]
    Environment="HOME=/opt/urserver"
    Type=forking
    PIDFile=/opt/urserver/.urserver/urserver.pid
    ExecStartPre=/bin/chmod 777 /var/run/sdp
    ExecStart=/opt/urserver/urserver-start --no-manager --no-notify
    ExecStop=/opt/urserver/urserver-stop

    RemainAfterExit=no
    Restart=on-failure
    RestartSec=5s

    [Install]
    WantedBy=default.target
```

Reload systemd daemon:

```
    user@machine:~$ sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

Restart bluetooth like this:

```
    user@machine:~$ sudo systemctl restart bluetooth
```

Start the new service:

```
    user@machine:~$ sudo systemctl start urserver
```

Enable the new service so it runs at startup:

```
    user@machine:~$ sudo systemctl enable urserver
```

THANK YOU [Leo Pedraza](https://askubuntu.com/users/584821/leo-pedraza), [Esa Nikulainen](https://askubuntu.com/users/855704/esa-nikulainen), and [Niklas](https://askubuntu.com/users/10609/niklas) for figuring out all the pieces!

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/944168)

Comment: I changed my post to provide an actual answer that combines the other answers into a more comprehensive step-by-step guide.

Comment: Having execute permissions should not be needed on a systemd service. I'd suggest removing the chmod.